# Modifying a collection's object's attribute removes all other attributes

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Adding to the array in an object in a collection object removes all other arrays in that object.

Consider a member of the events collection:

```
{
        "_id" : "EfEq7niEyLLatb7fb",
        "attendeeFavorites" : {
                "mRRYzNBaFEmuqCrLi" : [ ],
                "jbm8BJJ3PJCyWRJwz" : [ ],
                "9Ze5M6CkHdLwkJdbu" : [ ],
                "bH5q4himZawTTrbyc" : [ ]
        }
}
```

The keys of `attendeeFavorites` are userIds.  When that user is logged in, they may add strings to their corresponding array.  This is the active code for that:

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function () {

    var event = $scope.$meteorObject(Events, {}).subscribe('events');

    if( event.attendeeFavorites && event.attendeeFavorites[Meteor.userId()] ) {
        $scope.favorites = event.attendeeFavorites[Meteor.userId()];
    }
});

$scope.addFavorite = function(){
    $scope.favorites.push("x");
};
```

and the publish function:

```
Meteor.publish('events', function(){
    var projection = {
        name: 1
    };
    projection["attendeeFavorites."+this.userId] = 1;
    return Events.find({},{fields: projection});
});
```

For example, when user `9Ze5M6CkHdLwkJdbu` calls `addFavorite()`, an `x` is added to their `attendeeFavorites` array, except that it removes all other entries.  That turns the above into:

```
{
        "_id" : "EfEq7niEyLLatb7fb",
        "attendeeFavorites" : {
                "9Ze5M6CkHdLwkJdbu" : [
                        "x"
                ]
        }
}
```

Why is this happening??

*** EDIT ***
Reworking the publish function to

```
Meteor.publish('events', function(){
    return Events.find({});
});
```

fixes it, but this isn't a real solution, since I don't want users to be able to view other user's favorites array.

Comment: why don't you only list the ID's of the attendees and then maintain a separate list (perhaps a part of the user themself) that contains their individual favorites?

Comment: If you store something in the event object , anyone who subscribes to that object will have the possibility to see its contents. You could use angular's ng-show/hide to only display the favorites for one user, but the information would still be there. The only way to eliminate the possibility of other users seeing your favorites is to remove it from the original "public" event object.

Answer (score 0):

create a subscription that is user specific:

```
Meteor.publish('user_favorites').then(function() {
    return Events.find({attendeeFavorites: this.userId})
});
```

This will return only the favorites for that attendee

Then when you subscribe to it:

```
$scope.favorites = $scope.$meteorCollection(Events).subscribe('user_favorites');
```

But, if you read the angular-meteor docs, it's best to use the $scope.$meteorSubscribe:

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('user_favorites', function() {
    $scope.$meteorCollection(Events, false); // false will prevent it from updating the db automatically. remove if you do want it to update
});
```

$scope.$meteorSubscribe will terminate the subscription automatically when the scope is destroyed.

Keep in mind that I'm almost asleep, if this doesn't satisfy then I will fix it in the morning :)

Edit - I missed what you were trying to do, so try this:

In the even collection you keep a list of attendees by id:

```
{
    attendees: ['afasd89as8d923', 'q23rqwasdfj23', '..']
}
```

Then each user can contain a collection of attended events with associated favorites:

```
[
    {eventId: 'asdfasdf22q39f8', favorites: ['1', '2', '3']},
    {eventId: 'as2234assdf8989', favorites: ['asdf', 'foo', '3']}
]
```

How you model your favorites I don't know but it wouldn't matter. Each time a user visits a page he/she already has access to their own favorites, then you could simply only display the favorites associated with that event. This is of course if you have different fav's per event.

Really you wouldn't need to keep a list of attendees in each event, but that might come in handy for other purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My first publish function returns all events, but reveals only that user's array of favorites in the event.  I'm afraid yours returns all fields in every event that user has an attendeeFavorites entry in.

Comment: edit below original answer. Changing how you store your favorites would be the best bet.

Comment: I agree that is a better way to model the data, that I will probably go with in the end.  However now I am truly curious how I would solve the original problem, if you were to detach all meaning from the data.